# GMaps API Places Autocomplete & Directions - Map is not initializing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So I'm fairly new to not only HTML but also working with API's.  I've been working on implementing the Maps Javascript API, specifically the Places Autocomplete and Directions functionality.

Prior to this I simply initialized the map and it loaded properly every single time, but the moment I tried to (for testing purposes) implement the more complicated Places & Direction functionality it stopped initializing.

I browsed several forums and couldn't seem to find a solution to this problem.  If anyone could point out a potential issue within the code I would be grateful!

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
         <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <!-- GMAIL CLIENT KEY: 462218843122-16riskqb5201tfaeh51nrjqo3bec7h1c.apps.googleusercontent.com -->
                <!-- link to main stylesheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
      </head>

      <body>
            <!-- Navigation Bar -->
            <div class="navbar">
               <a href="#home">Home</a>
               <a href="SignIn.html">Sign In</a>
               <a href="#register">Register</a>
            </div>


            <!--
            <div class="about">
               <a>About</a><br />
               <a>We use the Firebase API to create and manage user accounts.</a><br /><br />
               <a>The user selects two travel points as displayed with the Google Maps API.</a><br /><br />
               <a>We poll United/Uber/Amtrack APIs for the available travel options.</a><br /><br />
               <a>We then email the user when a trip is available</a>
            </div>
         -->

            <div class="destInt">
               <a>Enter your Trip</a>
            </div>

         <div id="forms" style="position:absolute; top:30; left:0; height:50%; width: 50%">
            <form>

              <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
                  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
                  <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

                  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
                  <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

                  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
                  <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
               </div>


               <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
               placeholder="Enter an origin location"><br>

               <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
               placeholder="Enter a destination">



            </form>
         </div>





      <!-- Map -->
      <div id="map" style="position:absolute; top:35; right:0; height: 400px;  width: 48%; margin-right: 12px"></div>
      <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 30.615, lng: -96.342},
          zoom: 13
        });

        new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
      }

        /**
        * @constructor
       */
      function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.originPlaceId = null;
        this.destinationPlaceId = null;
        this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
        var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
        var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
        var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
        var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

        this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);

        var geocoder = new google.maps.geocoder;
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;




        })
      }

      // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
      // Autocomplete.
      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        var me = this;
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          me.travelMode = mode;
          me.route();
        });
      };

      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
        var me = this;
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.place_id) {
            window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
            return;
          }
          if (mode === 'ORIG') {
            me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
          } else {
            me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
          }
          me.route();
        });

      };

      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
        if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
          return;
        }
        var me = this;

        this.directionsService.route({
          origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
          destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
          travelMode: this.travelMode
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      };

      </script>
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY API KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
    </script>
   <!-- End of Map -->      

      </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be these lines:

```
    // these lines are invalid
    var geocoder = new google.maps.geocoder;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;




    }) // this is not tied to anything
```

You have some extra brackets. You also have a couple lines of invalid code. If you want to invoke those constructors you need to call them `()`